# Moving from Xcode 3.2.2 to Xcode 3.2.3?

Tags: xcode, ios4

I developed a complete application using xcode 3.2.2 and now want submit it to app store. 
Before that I need to compile it using xcode 3.2.3 for iOS 4.0.

I opened the xcode 3.2.2 project in Xcode 3.2.3 and tried to run on device with OS4.0, It gives me an error..

> "Error from debugger: The program being debugged is not being run ."

What should I do to build my project for iOS 4.0, without doing any major changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discover the problem. I implemented reachability in my app. I used the  "Reachability.h" and "Reachability.m" from Reachability sample. These files were old. The Reachability sample is updated. There are few changes in the .m file in the updated version.

I just replaced old files with new one and my app now compiled and works fine on iOS4...

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode. There are a lot of problems with the debugger for 3.2.3. =(

Also, for 4.0 you have to add some different methods to UIApp delegate at least.

Comment: Hi Chris,
I did that, even I restart my iPhone and mac as well. But the problem is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error "the program being debugged is not being run" when I updated Xcode.

It was frustrating but all that I did to solve it was to delete the old version of my app that was installed on my iPhone.  Then did a build and run on the device and the new version was installed.  Runs fine now.